[Odoo][v15] Create One2Many ralation to field.Reference as inverse_name
I have a 2 models:
class DiscountLineMixin(models.AbstractModel):

    _name = "discount.line.mixin"
    _description = "Discount Line Mixin"

    product_discountlist_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name="discountlist.percent",
        inverse_name="order_line_id",
        string="Product discountlist item effective_percent",
    )

and
class ProductDiscountPercent(models.Model):

    _name = "discountlist.percent"
    _description = "Discountlist rules discountlist per order line"

    model_name = fields.Char()
    record_id = fields.Integer()
    order_line_id = fields.Reference(
        selection="_select_target_model",
        string="Order Line",
    )
    discountlist_item_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name="product.discountlist.item",
        string="Discountlist item",
    )
    effective_percent = fields.Float(
        "Effective Percentage Price",
    )

    @api.model
    def _select_target_model(self):
        models = self.env["ir.model"].search([])
        return [(model.model, model.name) for model in models]

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if "model_name" in vals and "record_id" in vals:
            vals["order_line_id"] = f"{vals['model_name']},{vals['record_id']}"
        return super(ProductDiscountPercent, self).create(
            vals
        )

    def write(self, vals):
        if "model_name" in vals or "record_id" in vals:
            for record in self:
                model_name = vals.get("model_name", record.model_name)
                record_id = vals.get("record_id", record.record_id)
                vals["order_line_id"] = f"{model_name},{record_id}"
        return super(ProductDiscountPercent, self).write(vals)

I wanna create a one2many relation from Abstract model to normal model.
But when i create a record from AbstractModel by:
new_values = [
                    (0, 0, {
                        "model_name": self._name,
                        "record_id": self.id,
                        "discountlist_item_id": discountlist_item.id,
                        "effective_percent": effective_discount,
                    }),
                ]
                self.write({"product_discountlist_ids": new_values})

or
discountlist_item_percent = self.env["discountlist.percent"].create({
    "model_name": self._name,
    "record_id": self.id,
    "discountlist_item_id": discountlist_item.id,
    "effective_percent": effective_discount
})
self.product_discountlist_ids = [(4, discountlist_item_percent.id)]  

in both cases i have a created discountlist_item_percent record but adding reference to product_discountlist_ids not work.
In debugger i have:
self.product_discountlist_ids = discountlist.percent()
discountlist_item_percent = discountlist.percent(284,)

I assume that the problem is with using field.Reference for inverse_name in One2Many, but not sure how to fix this to work. I need to have Reference because this abstract model is used in many other models.

This cannot work technically because reference fields are not integers and therefore not foreign keys in the database. Accordingly, Odoo cannot resolve such a relation.

@CZoellner thx for answer. Now i know why it's not work :)

I will write an alternative as answer.

You could compute it on base of a reference field:
class ProductDiscountPercent(models.Model):

    _name = "discountlist.percent"

    # change the reference field
    order_line_reference = fields.Reference(
        selection="_select_target_model",
        string="Order Line",
    )
    # compute order_line_id on base of reference field
    order_line_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name="discountlist.percent",
        compute="_compute_order_line_id",
        string="Order Line",
        store=True,
    )

    @api.depends("order_line_reference")
    def _compute_order_line_id(self):
        for record in self:
            if (record.order_line_reference and
                record.order_line_reference._name == "discountlist.percent"):
                order_line_id = record.order_line_reference.id
                record.order_line_id = order_line_id
            else:
                record.order_line_id = False

